Relation between $L^2$-norm of harmonic forms and mass in some other (co-)homology theory
Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold.
Let $[\omega] \in H^k_{dR}(M)$ be a deRham cohomology class.
Then $[\omega]$ contains a unique harmonic $k$-form, say $\omega \in \Omega^k(M)$.
On the other hand, deRham cohomology groups are in 1-to-1 correspondence with other (co-)homology groups, such as the current homology groups $H^k(M)$.
Say that under this correspondence we have
$$[\omega] \mapsto [\alpha] \in H_k(M).$$

Question:
Is there some norm $||\cdot||$ on $H^k(M)$ such that $||[\alpha]||=||\omega||_{L^2}$?

